# How can i sum values that are unique which are connected to an id which is connected to a different id on which the summation needs to be based upon?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum, data-warehouse

I have a Database Warehouse. That database warehouse has to have measures but i can't seem to get the measure to work as i wanted.

The measure is gonna be calculated by a dimension called document here is a table of what is currently in it:

```
document_id client_id   contract    size
12  4   NULL    431
13  4   NULL    2543
14  5   NULL    2565
15  8   NULL    2345
```

I try to make a measure in the fact table that sums up the document_id's and combines their size. But because its a database warehouse the data is not normalized so in the fact table there are multiple rows which have the same document id so if i sum it it won't work i'll get this data if i sum it:

```
company_id  contract_id user_id task_id document_id insertion_date  size_total
4   28  14  26  12  2021-01-16  431
4   28  14  27  12  2021-01-16  431
4   28  14  28  12  2021-01-16  431
4   28  14  29  12  2021-01-16  431
4   28  14  30  12  2021-01-16  431
4   28  14  26  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   28  14  27  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   28  14  28  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   28  14  29  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   28  14  30  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   29  14  26  12  2021-01-16  431
4   29  14  27  12  2021-01-16  431
4   29  14  28  12  2021-01-16  431
4   29  14  29  12  2021-01-16  431
4   29  14  30  12  2021-01-16  431
4   29  14  26  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   29  14  27  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   29  14  28  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   29  14  29  13  2021-01-16  2543
4   29  14  30  13  2021-01-16  2543
5   30  15  31  14  2021-01-16  2565
5   30  15  32  14  2021-01-16  2565
6   NULL    16  33  NULL    2021-01-16  NULL
6   NULL    16  34  NULL    2021-01-16  NULL
6   NULL    16  35  NULL    2021-01-16  NULL
6   NULL    17  33  NULL    2021-01-16  NULL
6   NULL    17  34  NULL    2021-01-16  NULL
6   NULL    17  35  NULL    2021-01-16  NULL
7   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2021-01-16  NULL
8   31  18  36  15  2021-01-16  2345
```

As you can see on the previous data you saw that company_id 4 had 2 documents combined the size was:431 +2543 = 2974 but i get different answers in the measure total_size. I want to have a total_size which combines unique ID's based upon their owner which is the company_id. I tried to do the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
insert into [Stg_zone].[customer_usage]  
( size_total, company_id,contract_id,user_id,
task_id,document_id,insertion_date) 
select  
   sum ([size]) as size_total,
   cu.[client_id] ,
   cont.[contract_id],
   usr.[user_id],
   tsk.[task_id],
   doc.[document_id] ,
  SYSDATETIME ( )   as insertion_date

  FROM   [Stg_zone].[company] cu
    left JOIN dbo.contract cont ON (cont.client_id=cu.client_id)
    left JOIN dbo.[user] usr ON (usr.client_id=cu.client_id)
    left JOIN dbo.document doc ON (doc.client_id=cu.client_id)
    left JOIN dbo.task tsk ON (tsk.client_id=cu.client_id)

group by 
cu.[client_id] ,
cont.[contract_id],
usr.[user_id],
tsk.[task_id],
doc.[document_id],
doc.size,
usr.role
```

Does anybody know how i can fix this issue ?

Comment: You have a real data modeling problem if the facts in your fact table do not add up to real totals.  You may need to consider more drastic restructuring of the application.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any advice on how to fix this ?